# read files from directory and filter files from Java

Tags: java, performance

The following codes goes through all directories and sub-directories and outputs just .java files;

```
import java.io.File;


public class DirectoryReader {
    private static String extension = "none";
    private static String fileName;

    public static void main(String[] args ){
        String dir = "C:/tmp";
        File aFile = new File(dir);
        ReadDirectory(aFile);
    }
    private static void ReadDirectory(File aFile) {
        File[] listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
        if (aFile.isDirectory()) {
             listOfFiles = aFile.listFiles();
            if(listOfFiles!=null) {
                for(int i=0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++  ) {
                    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {

                        fileName = listOfFiles[i].toString();
                        int dotPos = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
                        if (dotPos > 0) {
                            extension = fileName.substring(dotPos);
                        }                       
                        if (extension.equals(".java")) {
                        System.out.println("FILE:" + listOfFiles[i] );
                        }
                    }           
                    if(listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                        ReadDirectory(listOfFiles[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Is this efficient? What could be done to increase the speed?

All ideas are welcome.

Comment: There is a bug: files without extension will be treated as when they have the last extension seen by the program. No need to call listFiles twice. Use .getPath() and not .toString() to get file path (same result, better readability)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My comments:

- Possible bug: `extension` is not reset. Think about what happens if you ecounter `file1.java` and thes `file2` (without a `.`-character?)

  Suggestion: put

  ```
  if (extension.equals(".java"))
      System.out.println("FILE:" + listOfFiles[i] );
  ```

  inside the body of the `if (dotPos > 0)`
- `ReadDirectory` is a method and should accourding to convention have small first letter: `readDirectory`
- You could clean up the code a bit by using the for-each loop:

  ```
  for(File f : listOfFiles) {
      if (f.isFile()) {
          // ...
      }           
      if(f.isDirectory()) {
          readDirectory(f);
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 7, I would consider something like:

```
Files.walkFileTree(aFile.toPath(), new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>()
{
  public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs)
  {
    if(file.getFileName().endsWith(".java")
    {
      System.out.println("FILE:" + file );
    }
    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
  }
});
```

This may not be faster, but I find it more readable.

EDIT: I removed the current Java example.  `listFiles` is not recursive, so you can use it, but you would have to use your own recursion.  You would also either need two `listFiles` calls (for Java files and directories), or you would need a `FileFilter` that matches both.  In the latter case, you would have to check every file in the returned array to see which it is.

Comment: file.getName() should be replaced with file.getFileName(), because getName(index) expects as a parameter the name of the element to return

Answer (score 0):

Use StringBuffer instead of System.out. Recursion is always slower albeit more concise.